# problem with enabling anonymous to site collection

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication

I have a problem enabling anonymous access to a site collection. I followed the steps at this [site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/3985/), but at step 2 section 3 I have a problem where the permission control is disabled.

[image: the message from the permission tools]

I am logged in using administrator account. How can I solve this?

Update :
when i put the mouse over permission tools Ribon i got this message "this control is currently disabled"

Comment: please add picture again, it didnt seem to work

Comment: stack exchange prevent me from this i need 10 more rep to do it

Comment: ok, you can either wait for your rep to increase or upload screenshot to an external server and link to it

Comment: What do you mean with "administrator account"? Site Collection Admin? Farm Admin? Local admin? Domain Admin?

Comment: site collection admin  and the farm admin

Comment: Is anonymous access allowed at the web application level?

Comment: @PirateEric is it's allowed

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "Stop inheriting permissions" then you can see "Anonymous Permission" choice.

Comment: how it's all disabled ?

Comment: @BigOmar Did that help you?  Actually, i just verified that by default, if you have publishing features turned on, the "Style Library" and "Site Collection Images" may have custom permissions set on them to assist with publishing workflows.  Could you post the Web Application level configuration steps that you took?  Also, you will need to reset your web server before you can proceed with allowing the permissions at lower levels.